# Resizing UITableViewCell contentview width.

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to make a UITableViewCell width to be 280 and start at (20,0)

meaning there should be 20 points insets on the X axis for the cell.

However, when I change the table cell's contentview frame - the entire cell is behind some black square that is of the size that I want
and my new cell looks like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7o8h64ite3tbxef/Screenshot%202014-04-06%2017.11.30.png)

This is my code for this:
in my viewDidLoad of the tableViewController

```
[tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:[self layoutName] bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:[self cellIdentifier]];
```

initialize of the cell

```
    -(void)initialize{
//    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
//    [self setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    self.backgroundView = [[WBChildCellBackground alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectInset([self frame], 20, 0)];
    [self.backgroundView setHidden:YES];
   self.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
    self.autoresizingMask =UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;

    self.contentView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;
    self.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    self.contentView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    self.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;
    self.originalFrame = self.frame;

}
```

And then I call this code:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    CGRect frame = self.bounds;
        frame.origin.x = frame.origin.x + self.cellInset;
        frame.size.width = frame.size.width - 2*self.cellInset;
      if(self.cellInset == 0){
            frame = self.originalFrame;
       }
    self.contentView.bounds = frame;
    [self.contentView layoutSubviews];

}
-(void)setCellInset:(CGFloat)cellInset{
    _cellInset = cellInset;
    [self layoutSubviews];
}
```

why doesn't my cell change the way I want?